# Enable Access Logs for Classic Load Balancer: Bucket does not appear in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I set up an S3 bucket following [Enable Access Logs for Your Classic Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-access-logs.html#attach-bucket-policy) but I accidentally used the ap-southeast-2 account ID rather than the us-east-1 account ID in the bucket policy.

As a result the bucket does not show up in the AWS console or in the CLI and any attempt to do CLI operations on it return an AccessDenied error.

How can I delete this bucket so I can recreate it with the correct account ID in the bucket policy? It's my AWS account so permissions shouldn't be a problem in theory.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access/ (generate a root user access key under My Security Credentials -> Access keys then use it to run delete-bucket-policy using aws-cli) should be the solution but I still get an AccessDenied error.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the Bucket Policy.

That documentation page takes you through the following steps:

1. Create an Amazon S3 Bucket: This is created in your own account and should appear immediately in the management console.
2. **Attach a Policy to Your S3 Bucket:** This grants permission for the Access Logs service to write to your bucket.
3. Enable Access Logs

If you made a mistake in the Bucket Policy, you can select the bucket in the Amazon S3 management console and edit the Bucket Policy.

The bucket policy merely grants access to another account. It will not prevent you from being able to access/edit your bucket.

Comment: I don't see the bucket in the console or through the API though - it's like the policy I've given it has hidden in from me completely.

Comment: A Bucket Policy cannot "hide" a bucket. You either have permissions to list _ALL_ buckets in your account or _NONE_ of the buckets. Therefore, either the bucket was not created, or it was created in a different AWS Account.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure why it's not showing up then - I'm using CloudFormation and had no trouble when I deployed to an ap-southeast-2 account. The only thing that changed here is the region so I'm not sure how it could have ended up belonging to a different account.

Comment: If you are using CloudFormation and the stack was rolled-back, then the bucket would have been deleted (unless you have created a Deletion Policy).

Comment: I didn't create a deletion policy and things were rolled back due to an unrelated error in a previous run. I tried deleting the stack too but the bucket wasn't deleted.